# TypeScript's Intersection Type is like merging? But if primitive it is really intersection

Tags: typescript

I have a hard time understanding why in TypeScript, the intersection `&` is like "merging":

```
type CEO = {
  name: string,
  boardToReportTo: string
};

type Employee = {
  name: string,
  manager: string
};

type Both = CEO & Employee;
```

So now, `Both` can have the properties of `name`, `boardToReportTo`, and `manager`. It is like a "merging", not intersection, which would be just `name`. (And this "merging" is like a "union")

However, if it is primitive:

```
type Foo = string & number;
```

Now it is not "merging" any more like above. Now it really is intersection, meaning it is `never`, or `bottom`, or `empty`.

So I don't quite understand, is it "merging" or is it "intersection" really, because it seems sometimes it is one, and sometimes it is the other.

Comment: I never heard `&` be described as "merging" but there is some sense to it. Good question, made me think.

Answer (score 2):

*Intersection* of non-primitive types can't be called just merging. It does merge and intersect at the same time.

- The fields that are missing in one of the objects are merged in the result type.

```
type Param1 = {
  a: string;
};

type Param2 = {
  b: number;
};

// {
//   a: string;
//   b: number;
// }
type Result = Param1 & Param2;
```

- The fields that exist in both of the objects are intersected:

```
type Param1 = {
  a: string;
};

type Param2 = {
  a: number;
};

// never
type Result = (Param1 & Param2)['a'];
```

Answer (score 1):

In TypeScript, the concept you are referring to is called "intersection types". When you define a type using the  `&`  operator, such as  Both = CEO & Employee , it creates a new type that has all the properties of both  `CEO`  and  `Employee` .
This is commonly referred to as "merging" because the resulting type merges the properties of the individual types.

In the example you provided, the type  `Both`  can have the properties  `name` ,  `boardToReportTo` , and  `manager` .
It is not just limited to the property  `name`  as you mentioned. This behavior is consistent with intersection types in TypeScript.

However, when you use intersection types with primitive types, such as  Foo = string & number , the resulting type becomes an empty type. This is because there is no value that can simultaneously be both a string and a number. Therefore, the intersection of  `string`  and  `number`  results in a type that cannot have any valid values.

In summary, intersection types in TypeScript allow you to create new types that merge the properties of the individual types involved. It is not the same as the concept of intersection in set theory. The behavior of intersection types depends on the types being intersected.

Answer (score 1):

This all comes from the [set logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)) you may have learned in math in school.

We have a set of A's and a set of B's. The *intersection of the sets* A & B is the set of things that are *both* A and B.

If we have the set of fruits (apples, oranges, blueberries, etc) and a set of things that are yellow (yield signs, dump trucks, the sun, etc) and we take the intersection of the two we wind up with yellow fruits (ex. banana).

The same logic applies to Typescript.

If we have an A:

```
type A = {
  a: string
}
```

and a B

```
type B = {
  b: number
}
```

then the intersection A & B is going to be things that are *both* A *and* B:

```
const x: A & B = {
  a: 'hi', // makes it structurally an A
  b: 5,    // makes it structurally a B
};
```

because it matches the schema for A, and it matches the schema of B. But when we apply that same logic to primitives, it is very clear that the set of things that are e.g. *both* numbers *and* strings is the *empty set*. There is no value that is simultaneously a number and a string, so we call that type `never`.

```
const foo: string & number = ?; // nothing satisfies this type
```

So there isn't really a difference between how it treats primitives vs object types, the underlying logic is the same for both. The object types don't really "merge", although I can definitely see where that framing makes sense and where you got it from.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoKUCGAuKBnYATgJYB2A5igL4oqiRQBCCyaUARjiQK4C2bEBKjQDGAexL4oADxxwAZI2ap02KAHIAFkTUAaVhygBWPZQDcNOtAAioiLgByo4AHVRBANbN8xclAXc+AXMgA)

Comment: so it is from the fundamental: it is be A AND B, so when it is object properties, we merge the two sets of properties (like a union), so that it can be A AND B, while for primitive, there is no way to merge it like the object definition, so it is empty. What about CEO is `name: string` and Employee is for some reason `name: number`? Then it cannot be `&` any more? Ok, just tried it, then `name` becomes type `never`

Comment: @StefanieGauss correct, and any time you see `never` it comes from an attempt to define a type that logically doesn't make sense, like a thing that is simultaneously a number and a string.

Answer (score 0):

Think of `type A = B & C` as meaning: any object of type `A` can be interpreted as a a `B` *and* a `C` simultaneously.

Then both examples make sense: An object which can be interpreted as a `CEO` or `Employee` must have all of the properties of both classes, an object that can be interpreted as both a string and number simply does not exist.

More complex examples naturally follow: If both `B` and `C` have a field called `x` and if an object `o` is both a `B` and a `C`, then `o.x` must exist and obey all restrictions that `B` and `C` put on `x`.

So there is no special casing for primitives. Types describe mathematical sets, and `&` is an intersection of sets.